# Android Vertical Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout

I keep getting this error on running but no compile errors? here is the logcat and code for main.

```
05-25 12:29:25.543: W/dalvikvm(384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tablayout/com.example.tablayout.TablayoutActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.TabActivity.ensureTabHost(TabActivity.java:114)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.TabActivity.getTabHost(TabActivity.java:136)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.example.tablayout.TablayoutActivity.<init>(TablayoutActivity.java:15)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-25 12:29:25.582: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  ... 11 more






    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:baselineAligned="false">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dip" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="0.2">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button android:layout_height="0dip" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_photos_tab"               
                android:id="@+id/artist_id" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="0dip" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_videos_tab"  
                android:id="@+id/album_id" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="0dip" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_songs_tab"   
                android:id="@+id/song_id" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler"/>
    </LinearLayout> 
    </FrameLayout>       
    <FrameLayout 
     android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
     android:layout_width="0dip" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

here is the main.java file, this way you can see how it was a global variable and where i removed it from.  Also added the buttons globally instead of locally to that one spot.

```
    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TabHost;
   import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

   public class TablayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button artistButton, songButton, videosButton;
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Photos
    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator("Photos",   getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    // Tab for Songs
    TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
    songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    // Tab for Videos
    TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
    videospec.setIndicator("Videos",         getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
    Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
    videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
    tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab




   }

    public void tabHandler(View target){
    artistButton.setSelected(false);
    videosButton.setSelected(false);
    songButton.setSelected(false);
    if(target.getId() == R.id.artist_id){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        artistButton.setSelected(true);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.album_id){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        videosButton.setSelected(true);
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.song_id){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        songButton.setSelected(true);
    }
   };

    }
```

Comment: cleaned, closed out adb, and even tried to run on my phone as emulator.  still no luck and the ddms lights up more red than before cleaning.

Comment: Good job cleaning up the exception trace, by the way.

Comment: that was added by another, I just accepted the change.  so thank you to them lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to call `getTabHost()` somewhere in your constructor or in setting a field on your class.  You have to call it from within `onCreate()` since `getTabHost()` down deep tries to get the current window, which isn't created yet at constructor time.

Any time after `onCreate()` has been called will be fine.

Comment: yeah I made the getTabHost a global variable, it didn't show any errors but when i don't i get an error that doesn't allow me to access it with the tabs I have.  Should i use a onclick handler instead of what is there.

Comment: Perhaps seeing your code would help us understand a bit more.  You can assign getTabHost() to a global variable, just don't assign it until during or after onCreate().  There of course won't be anything syntactically wrong with doing so, so you wouldn't see any errors per se.

Comment: I updated the code so you could see what i was talking about, i even commented out where i switched the getTabHost variable

Comment: Do you mean you tried it with getTabHost() inside onCreate() and it still did't work?  If you did, I hope you remembered to comment out the global variable before trying it.  I've made worse mistakes before...

Comment: yeah i think the problem is the added function at the bottom. I can't get it to function call the tabHost so it is having problems, is there another way to use it. And I put the getTabHost () back into the local of on create, its the second function call that is still messed up

Comment: Not sure what you are using that tabHandler() method for anyway.  It looks kind of dubious as the tab host really handles all the setting of the current tabs and highlighting the appropriate tab on selection.  What does it even mean for a button to be "selected" in this context?  Regardless, you can call a super method like getTabHost() anywhere in the class, regardless of what method you are in.  That's just Java...

Comment: so if i changed the function tabhandler to an onclick method how would i use the gettabHost function.  during the onclick and make the button names the same as the tab id.  This way the tabhost knows its waiting on the button click by the user.  The endgame for this is simply just wanting a tab host to stand vertically on the side of  the screen but I couldn't get it to generate properly other than through this method.  Now it sets the xml up properly but i cant use the tabs?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response... So long as your function tabhandler is invoked after onCreate() there is no issue.  Rather than assigning the result of getTabHost() to a class-level field, just call it inside your function, maybe even assigning the result to a local variable there instead.

Comment: how do you do that, i tried to get it as a function and it fc every time.  I finally got it to stop fcing only so that when i push a button it fcs.  I am confused on this one.

Comment: What is the exception that it is force closing on now?

Comment: i need to update the code above but onClick is the when it FC.  I have the name of the buttons the same as the name of the tabs and the tabs set to invisible.  Should I set the name of the buttons to their own identifier then onclick switch the tabs to either setselected or setCurrentTab.

Comment: If you look at some of the example code for TabActivity, you will notice that the tab buttons themselves are highlighted by the TabActivity and that switching between tabs is built in.  You don't need to code for that.

Comment: it all worked great without the buttons just using tabs but i wanted to put it sideways so the tabs have to sit vertically.  its when I tried to rotate it is now that I am having the issue.  I am going to try to remove the buttons and leave the tabs there and fix it that way.

Comment: Interesting use case, I don't believe I have ever tried to arrange the tabs vertically.